# C# background worker- how to trigger it for a repetitive task

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, deque

I am receiving data from a serial port, placing each line into a queue and then de-queuing the lines, formatting them slightly (removing some leading characters, trimming etc), and then displaying the formatted lines in a listbox.

I am using a Timer to fire the Dequeuing method every 200ms. Everything is working but it seems to be a bit sluggish/slow.

I am considering using a BackgroundWorker to handle the de-queuing and formatting but im getting stuck.

I tried to start the backgroundworker in FormLoad, but quickly realized it would run through the code only once. I tried a label and goto inside the backgroundworker code to create a loop (i know, not good) but that got me high CPU usage and didnt even work.

I also tried using " backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); " in my serial received event to run it every time new data comes in but that throws the 'Background worker currently busy" exception

So, I need the background worker to continuously process the queue (dequeue).

Code: heres my data received event, and below that my dequeuing code thats sitting in the backgroundworker.  Any help much appreciated.

```
//  Serial Data Received
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(
    object sender, 
    System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    RxString = serialPort1.ReadTo("\u0003");
    q.Enqueue(RxString);
}
```

Next Code is the dequeue code:

```
//  Dequeue items, format, then display in listbox
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (q.Count == 0)
    {
        // do nothing if q is empty
    }
    else
        do
        {
            output = (q.Dequeue().ToString());
            output = output.TrimStart(new char[] { (char)02 }); 
            output = output.TrimEnd(new char[] { (char)03 });

            if (output.StartsWith("C"))
            {
                ClearAll();
            }
            else if (output.StartsWith("W98"))
            {
                txtTax.Text = (output.Remove(0, 5));
            }
            else if (output.StartsWith("W99"))
            {
                txtTotal.Text = (output.Remove(0, 24));
            }
            else
            {  
                listOrderItems.Items.Add(output.Remove(0, 5));
                listOrderItems.SelectedIndex = listOrderItems.Items.Count - 1;
            }
        } while (q.Count > 0);
}
```

Comment: Too many threads.  You already got one handed to you on a silver platter: the DataReceived event runs on a threadpool thread.  Do the message process there.  Then use Control.BeginInvoke to update any UI.

Comment: @Hans: Answers go down there (even short ones)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, users get cranky about that.

Comment: Hans, does your comment mean that the DataReceived event is already running in something that is similar to a BackgroundWorker? If so, does you 'too many threads' comment mean that its not good to create extra threads? how does one determine how many threads are too many?   When you say .."do the message process there" do you mean move all the formatting code into the DR event??  If so this begs another question: Do I even need a BgW ?  I need this to be responsive.  This program doesnt do anything too complicated, but I need it to be fast and stable.

Comment: i put my formatting code into the DataRec. event handler. it does not work well at all.

Comment: Your processing doesn't involve much, so is it just the UI that is slow to update/respond? How many lines end up in your list? Maybe it's the listbox that is the problem...could you use something more lightweight like a label or text box?

Answer (score 0):

i do not see the point parsing your string in a different thread. it is not a long running procedure, and since your running in the background thread, it seems that you forgot to `Invoke` to the windows thread. here is my solution,

```
using System.IO.Ports;    


static void ParseData(ref string data)
{
    data = data.TrimStart(new char[] { (char)02 }); 
    data = data.TrimEnd(new char[] { (char)03 });  
}    

private void UpdateControlsWithData(string data)
{
    Action action;
    if(data.StartsWith("C")
    {
        action = () => ClearAll();
    }
    else if(data.StartsWith("W98"))
    {
        action = () => { txtTax.Text = data.Remove(0, 5); };
    }
    else if(data.StartsWith("W99"))
    {
        action = () => { txtTotal.Text = data.Remove(0, 24); };
    }
    else
    {
        action = () => { 
            listOrderItems.Items.Add(data.Remove(0, 5));
            listOrderItems.SelectedIndex = listOrderItems.Items.Count - 1;
        };
    }
    if(this.InvokeRequired()) this.Invoke(action);
    else action();
}

private void HandleDataReceived()
{
    string data = serialPort1.ReadTo("\u0003");
    ParseData(ref data);
    UpdateControlsWithData(data);
}

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    this.HandleDataReceived();
}
```

Comment: Just as a courtesy follow up- I indeed did not need to launch any new threads. I created a new Queue to hold my serial data line by line as my primary incoming data handler.  I then used a timer to dequeue all the items in the queue and manipulate, format, and display them in my listbox and lablels. thanks to those who chimed in!